# What is the "parent" global group?

Tags: active-directory, groups

I've been reading about Group Scope for Groups within Microsoft's Active Directory from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc755692(v=ws.10).aspx. However, I find the following in relation to the membership of global groups to be somewhat unclear:

> Global
>
> - Accounts from the same domain as the **parent** global group
> - Global groups from the same domain as the **parent** global group

The author may not have intended to imply that there is a parent-child relationship between groups, however given the presence of the word parent in both points it is difficult to read what is written any other way.

After reading what's written I find myself asking "What parent global group?".
Is there a parent-child relationship between groups? If so, how do you determine the parent group? If not, what did the author intend these points to actually say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means global groups that the other principals are a member of.

For example, if you have `Global Group A` and it contains `Global Group B` then A would be the parent global group. In practice, no one uses this nomenclature. And I would also agree that it's a poorly written article.

Comment: The table in the article is overly complicated because it tries to generalize the relationship too much. I prefer this [summary of group scopes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UIL3i.jpg). It's a bit longer, but it's perfectly clear.

Comment: MDMarra - Thank you for clearing that up. I dismissed that interpretation because it didn't seem right to refer to Microsoft or the Cleveland Cavs as the parent global group of Bill Gates or LeBron James respectively. @Daniel: Thank you for the helpful table it confirmed the understanding I had built up.